# Why does the variac make a "zing" sound during testing?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, testing, power-factor-correction

I've tested my prototype transition mode 80 W boost PFC with 220 VAC input and 400 VDC output. When I supply the Vcc of the controller and start the switching MOSFET, after a couple of minutes, the variac makes a "zing" sound and By cutting off the VCC power supply, the sound stopped. What is the reason? Is it harmful and/or dangerous?

[image]

Comment: Are you saturating the transformer T1? What does your oscilloscope say during the event?

Comment: @winny
it seemed that it was working correctly and the output reached 400 volts perfectly thus I think T1 was not saturated.

Comment: The variac features a highly-inductive output which can interact with the boost converter input impedance. If the whole thing becomes unstable, then the variac sings. For testing a PFC, and its output current in particular, the best is to use a true solid-state ac source whose output impedance is quite low. The variac helps for debug but not for real PFC tests, furthermore if you want to assess input current distortion.

Comment: Please measure. Is your input section exactly as in the schematic above? Have you simulated it?

Comment: @winny yes it is exactly as the schematic. Yes the simulation is also done and work perfectly.

Comment: What’s your peak inductor current in simulation at WCS? What’s your T1 saturation current? What’s the inductance of your variac?

Comment: In general, using a Variac on a PFC stage is asking for trouble.  When designing and testing, I like to power PFC's from a series-connected incandescent lightbulb for protection; if the bulb stays lit, something is wrong.  Once you're sure the PFC and rest of power supply is working properly and safely, remove the bulb.  To test at different voltages, use the real source (120, 240) or a transformer designed for this.